# Stop Background-img from resizing when shrinking the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I've been trying to stop the **background-img** from resizing, because It interferes with this JavaScript code that keep the red dots or **pointer** on the background-img as I resize the browser.

**PROBLEM:**
When re-sizing the browser window the background-img resizes and the red-dots stay in the same place. I want it to STOP resizing.
[image]

**WHAT I WANT**:

**1.** I want the red dots to **NOT MOVE** from the specific part of the background-img. I'm guessing we have to tweak the JavaScript for this.

**2.** When I resize or open a smaller browser window the background-Image should **STAY THE SAME SIZE**, and whatever is out of view should stay out of view.I'm assuming this is a CSS issue. 
[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1doxa1y/4/)

Please, let me know what change I should make to the JavaScript to make sure the red dots stay in the same place, and the CSS to make sure the background-img is not resized but left out of view. Thank you!
**CSS:**

```
.container {
    background:url(http://www.seomofo.com/downloads/new-google-logo-knockoff.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 380px;
     background-size:contain;
}

.wrapper  {     background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #0d58a6, #0a488a);}
.top {height:100%; width:1000px: background:blue; }

.pointer {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#F00;
    position:fixed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div id="pointer1" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer2" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer3" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer4" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer5" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer6" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer7" class="pointer"></div>
<div id="pointer8" class="pointer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var image = { width: 550, height: 190 };

var target = new Array();
target[0] = { x: 184, y: 88 };
target[1] = { x: 284, y: 88 };
target[2] = { x: 384, y: 88 };
target[3] = { x: 484, y: 88 };
target[4] = { x: 184, y: 150 };
target[5] = { x: 284, y: 150 };
target[6] = { x: 384, y: 150 };
target[7] = { x: 484, y: 150 };

var pointer = new Array();
pointer[0] = $('#pointer1');
pointer[1] = $('#pointer2');
pointer[2] = $('#pointer3');
pointer[3] = $('#pointer4');
pointer[4] = $('#pointer5');
pointer[5] = $('#pointer6');
pointer[6] = $('#pointer7');
pointer[7] = $('#pointer8');


$(document).ready(updatePointer);
$(window).resize(updatePointer);

function updatePointer() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    // Get largest dimension increase
    var xScale = windowWidth / image.width;
    var yScale = windowHeight / image.height;
    var scale;
    var yOffset = 0;
    var xOffset = 0;

    if (xScale > yScale) {
        // The image fits perfectly in x axis, stretched in y
        scale = xScale;
        yOffset = (windowHeight - (image.height * scale)) / 2;
    } else {
        // The image fits perfectly in y axis, stretched in x
        scale = yScale;
        xOffset = (windowWidth - (image.width * scale)) / 2;
    }

    var arrayLength = target.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        pointer[i].css('top', (target[i].y) * scale + yOffset);
        pointer[i].css('left', (target[i].x) * scale + xOffset);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.container` change `background-size:contain;` to a set number of pixels, something like `800px`.

Comment: How can I keep the red dots from staying in the same place like this https://jsfiddle.net/L1doxa1y/

Comment: Actually that works for the above answerm I may have to open another question for a more javascript specific approach, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try adding min-width in the body

```
width: 100% !important;
min-width: 1000px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```